# Is there a way to add html attribute on an ajax success function on return function?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am trying to add image on my autocomplete search drop box here is an image:

[image]

Imagine the border boxes are the images. The problem is, I cannot achieve how to do this, but I already have a startup code. I have already completed the autocomplete search function but I cannot append an image or pictures besides it.

Current Output:

[image]

Script

```
<script>
  var BASE_URL = "<?php echo base_url(); ?>";
 
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $( "#search_text" ).autocomplete({
 
        source: function(request, response) {
            $.ajax({
            url: BASE_URL + "dorms/search",
            data: {
                    term : request.term
             },
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(data){
               var resp = $.map(data,function(obj){
                    return "<img src='assets/images/dorms/"+ obj.image +"'> Room Type: " + obj.type + " - " + "Cost: P. " + obj.price + ".00";
               }); 
 
               response(resp);
            }
        });
    },
    minLength: 1
 });
});
 
</script>
```

Comment: Is `<image ...` a "component" you made or did you mean `<img ...`?

Comment: @kerbh0lz - sorry, it's img, but it goes the same with other html att like <b></b> etc. it shows the whole code.. like `<b>Single Room</b>` in the search box

Comment: @kerbh0lz - I have added my current output or problem.. please see the image above, thank you

Comment: Think you need to do this in _RenderItem instead of in the results themselves.

Answer (score 0):

The Response must be an array of Strings or Objects.

> An `array` of `strings`: `[ "Choice1", "Choice2" ]`

> An `array` of `objects` with label and value properties: `[ { label: "Choice1", value: "value1" }, ... ]`

> A `response` callback, which expects a single argument: the data to suggest to the user. This data should be filtered based on the provided term, and can be in any of the formats described above for simple local data. It's important when providing a custom source callback to handle errors during the request. You must always call the response callback even if you encounter an error. This ensures that the widget always has the correct state.

Consider the following the following code.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#search_text").autocomplete({
    source: function(request, response) {
      $.ajax({
        url: BASE_URL + "dorms/search",
        data: {
          term: request.term
        },
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data) {
          var resp = [];
          $.each(data, function(k, v) {
            resp.push({
              label: v.label,
              value: v.price,
              image: v.image,
              price: v.price,
              type: v.type
            });
          });
          response(resp);
        }
      });
    },
    minLength: 1,
    _renderItem: function(ul, item) {
      return $("<li>")
        .append("<div><img src='" + item.image + "' /> Room Type: " + item.type + " - Cost: P. " + item.price.toFixed(2) + "</div>")
        .appendTo(ul);
    }
  });
});
```

See Also: https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#custom-data

Comment: Hello sir, it only shows the Price. then everything is not shown, is there any way to fix this?

Comment: @CoderCodes please provide aMinimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example